# Is iCloud Backup issue will arise for applications build in lowers iOS SDK versions

Tags: ios4, icloud, ios5

I developed my application using Xcode 4.0.2 and iOS 4 SDK.  Currently i am storing lots of documents and files in the Document Directory.

From iOS5 onwards, files and documents stored in the Document directory will be moved to iCloud automatically when they sync up with iTunes.

My question is whether it will affect the iOS applications build with SDKs like iOS4 or iOS3.
Are we need add additional code to disable the backup option in lower versions also like iOS 5.1 iCloud disable feature.

Answer (score 0):

yes you need some additional code to prevent this back-up,please refer to the following link:
[iOS 5.0.1 : How to verify that the folder is marked as "Do not back up" for iCloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117284/ios-5-0-1-how-to-verify-that-the-folder-is-marked-as-do-not-back-up-for-iclo)