# How to check which files are stored on iCloud?

Tags: ios, cordova, icloud

My app have been rejected by Apple, and the cause is "Apps must follow the iOS Data Storage Guidelines or they will be rejected".

My app is based on Phonegap so it has many offline files(html,js,css) stored in `Documents/myApp` directory. I added `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` variable to the dir.

However, when I check the iCloud storage(setting->icloud->my iphone->manage), there is still more than 100kb data belongs to my app. Is there a way to find out which files are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test if the `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` flag has been applied to any particular file using the iOS Simulator.

After installing your app in the simulator, use the [SimPholders](http://simpholders.com/) application to locate the files of your installed app.

Then, as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117284/ios-5-0-1-how-to-verify-that-the-folder-is-marked-as-do-not-back-up-for-iclo?answertab=votes#answer-11272592), use `xattr` to verify if the attribute is set on a particular file. If there's no output then the attribute has not been set.