# How to know if a file is really excluded from an iCloud backup

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, backup, nsfilemanager

Is there any method for determining whether a specific file *actually is* being backed up to iCloud?  I don't mean whether it is *supposed* to be backed up or not, I mean whether there is a way to see what files were actually backed up?

This question may be considered a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117284/ios-5-0-1-how-to-verify-that-the-folder-is-marked-as-do-not-back-up-for-iclo), but I am asking something slightly different per my second sentence above.

I applied the NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey attribute to my file, but I used iExplorer to browse my iTunes backup and the file is in there so now I am not sure which if any of the following may be an issue:

1. If my file is being backed up despite the attribute (I have not verified that the attribute is there with the xattr command, but I will check tonight.)
2. If what iExplorer is showing me is not just what's in my backup.
3. If this is designed to exclude the file only from iCloud backups.  (I tried both encrypted and unencrypted backups.)

It did just occur to me that possibly I might have to set the attribute every time I save the file? (Particularly because I am using atomic writes which, as I understand it, create a new file every time which is then renamed as the original.)

---

### ** UPDATE **

After looking at the file created by the simulator with `xattr`, I figured out that apparently I do need to add the attribute every time I save the file, and now iExplorer shows that it is not in my iTunes backup.

So now I am wondering why my phone settings indicate that my app is backing up 29kb of data when the only other file I have is my 3k plist (NSUserDefaults) file.  (It's weird anyway since my other file is only 10k.  Maybe the 29k is a leftover figure from old data?  I am going to delete and reinstall the app fresh to check.)

Is there a more reliable way than the phone settings to see the app backup size?